# What is the equivalent of linux-ftools on CentOS?

Tags: caching, centos

Is there an equivalent of [linux-ftools](https://code.google.com/archive/p/linux-ftools/) on CentOS? I'm looking to identify which files are in the cache in a high-utilization situation (see the **buff/cache** column as follows):

```
[~]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        2.6G        5.9G        1.5G         22G         26G
Swap:           11G          0B         11G
```